# New line characters in script output treated differently by Atom and Notepad

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a little script which creates a .txt file and writes some data in there. When I view the .txt file in Atom, everything is from new line, like I wanted, but when I open that .txt file in notepad everything is in a single line. How to fix this?

This is a peace of code:

```
wstream.write(text + ':' + $(this).text());
wstream.write("\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is an end-of-line character issue. To get [platform-dependent EOL character](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol), use the following code:

```
const EOL = require('os').EOL;
// ... 
wstream.write(EOL);
```

That way your txt file will contain line endings that match the system you use to view the files.